# Run an invisible Linux -> VM on laptop

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So I have an OS I want to be my system's primary OS, but it's not supported by the hardware; that said, it runs just fine in a VM, and my system supports most desktop flavors of Linux just fine. All steps I know for hosting VMs on a system are for a server-style environment, but I want the host system for the VM to be near invisible - I want to turn on the system and boot as seamlessly as possible right into the VM at full screen, from startup, with as little overhead as possible (dropping off X Window and similar systems would be nice.) But I've yet to figure out how to do it (been looking at CLI-only versions of linux to host the VM, but all of them I find, I only manage to find instructions for remote connection, nothing for running it on the local machine.)

Comment: I'm trying to keep things as open-source as possible. If you know a better open-source solution for a VM, feel free to suggest, but it does need to run virtualbox VMs.

Comment: Create and run a shell script that starts the VM?  I am assuming you can start a VM via the terminal and if so, should be relatively easy to run a script with that command at the boot process if you can find the command to run.

Comment: Having a bare-bones Linux without a GUI run a GUI inside is probably not a good strategy. There are ways to run virtualization so that the GUI is visible to a remote client but you'd basically have to then run a local GUI to run the "remote" client locally anyway. Just go for a graphical Linux (but lightweight? LXDE is the lightest desktop I have tried IIRC).